# How to correct a vector index?

Tags: matlab, indexing, statistics, cluster-analysis

Ok so I am clustering data into clusters which are then indexed using a column. The data is in the form of motion vectors and so my data will look like this after being clustered:

```
[index x y x' y']
```

for example:

```
[1 3 5 4 6;
 1 4 6 5 7;
 2 3 5 4 6;
 2 8 9 9 3;
 3 2 3 2 4]
```

in above array there are 3 clusters, with clusters 1 and 2 each containing 2 vectors.

My problem is that I sometimes have to delete clusters based on certain criteria, and may be left with:

```
[2 3 5 4 6;
 2 8 9 9 3;
 3 2 3 2 4]
```

I want to be able to correct the index after deletion, so that it starts at 1 and ends with the number of clusters. So in this case replace the 2s with 1s and 3s with 2s.

Im sure there must be a simple way using a for loop but Ive been trying for a while and can't get ti right?

Answer (score 1):

A simple call to [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) will help you do that.  You can use the third output of it to assign each unique and new ID using the first column of the new data matrix (index vector) to replace its first column. Also, make sure you use the `'stable'` flag so that it assigns IDs in order of occurrence from top to bottom:

```
 %// Data setup
 A = [1 3 5 4 6;
      1 4 6 5 7;
      2 3 5 4 6;
      2 8 9 9 3;
      3 2 3 2 4];

 %-----
 B = A(3:end,:); %// Remove first two rows

 %// Go through the other IDs and reassign to unique IDs from 1 up to whatever
 %// is left
 [~,~,id] = unique(B(:,1), 'stable');

 %// Replace the first column of the new matrix with the new IDs
 B(:,1) = id; %// Replace first column with new IDs
```

We get:

```
>> B

B =

     1     3     5     4     6
     1     8     9     9     3
     2     2     3     2     4
```

Comment: I completely forgot about unique. :) +1 for simplicity

Comment: My pleasure. If either of us have helped, please consider accepting one of our answers. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your matrix is called `data`, try this:

```
>> data = [2 3 5 4 6;
           2 8 9 9 3;
           3 2 3 2 4]

data =

     2     3     5     4     6
     2     8     9     9     3
     3     2     3     2     4

>> data(:,1) = cumsum(diff(data([1 1:end], 1)) ~= 0) + 1

data =

     1     3     5     4     6
     1     8     9     9     3
     2     2     3     2     4
```

Comment: This is what I would have done if I didn't know about `unique` :) +1.